# Windows 8 Share Contract and Clipboard Hooks/Interception

Tags: winapi, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, hook

2 questions:

1) Is it possible to hook into the Share Broker in Windows 8 Metro, so that I am able to write a program that gets invoked each time an windows 8 app shares content with another windows 8 app? For example i would like to automatically make modifications to text content that is shared between apps. If so, i guess it would only be possible with Win32 API am I right?

2) Is the same thing possible for the Clipboard in Windows 8 Metro?

I guess WinRT is too sandboxed for writing such a global interception demon, but i could imagine that it is possible when using Win32...

thanks for you help!

Comment: There is no supported way of doing this. Imagine the havoc that would result.

Comment: Well why havoc? Global Hooks have been supported by all windows versions including windows 8. Why not support this for Metro also? I mean I can still do this in Windows 8 with Win32 API for desktop apps to hook into Clipboard etc... There should really be a way to manage this for Metro too shouldn't it?

Comment: And you've seen the havoc those global hooks have created. Hangs, crashes, everything randomly stops working because a hook had a bug.

Comment: Microsoft itself does hooking and binary patching.

Answer (score 0):

Although you can monitor the clipboard using Win32 there is no way (at least that I'm aware of) to intercept a Share. Share itself is considered a *contract* and contracts are the only means for communication between two applications or even between one application and the shell. Allowing another application to intercept and potentially modify the data sent across a contract could present a security risk for impersonation, data stealing, etc.